# how do I control movement of bouncing divs with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a single button that controls the bouncing movement of my `div`'s. In the default position, the ***space*** divs should form a static, single line.

Once the button is pressed, the divs should resume bouncing within the container.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwLpf1vr/5/)

```
function hitLR(el, bounding) {
    console.log($(el).data('vx'), $(el).data('vy'))
    if (el.offsetLeft <= 0 && $(el).data('vx') < 0) {
        console.log('LEFT');
        $(el).data('vx', -1 * $(el).data('vx'))
    }
    if ((el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth) >= bounding.offsetWidth) {
        console.log('RIGHT');
        $(el).data('vx',  -1 * $(el).data('vx'));
    }
    if (el.offsetTop <= 0 && $(el).data('vy') < 0) {
        console.log('TOP');
        $(el).data('vy', -1 * $(el).data('vy'));
    }
    if ((el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight) >= bounding.offsetHeight) {
        console.log('BOTTOM');
        $(el).data('vy', -1 * $(el).data('vy'));
    }
}

function mover(el, bounding) {
    hitLR(el, bounding);
    el.style.left = el.offsetLeft + $(el).data('vx') + 'px';
    el.style.top = el.offsetTop + $(el).data('vy') + 'px';

}

setInterval(function() {
    $('.bouncer').each(function(){

        mover(this, $('.bouncyHouse')[0]);
    });
}, 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) function to stop the movement.

See this **[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/qwLpf1vr/7/)**.

```js
function hitLR(el, bounding) {
  if (el.offsetLeft <= 0 && $(el).data('vx') < 0) {
    //console.log('LEFT');
    $(el).data('vx', -1 * $(el).data('vx'))
  }
  if ((el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth) >= bounding.offsetWidth) {
    //console.log('RIGHT');
    $(el).data('vx', -1 * $(el).data('vx'));
  }
  if (el.offsetTop <= 0 && $(el).data('vy') < 0) {
    //console.log('TOP');
    $(el).data('vy', -1 * $(el).data('vy'));
  }
  if ((el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight) >= bounding.offsetHeight) {
    //console.log('BOTTOM');
    $(el).data('vy', -1 * $(el).data('vy'));
  }
}

function mover(el, bounding) {
  hitLR(el, bounding);
  el.style.left = el.offsetLeft + $(el).data('vx') + 'px';
  el.style.top = el.offsetTop + $(el).data('vy') + 'px';
}

function moveIt() {
  $('.bouncer').each(function() {
    mover(this, $('.bouncyHouse')[0]);
  });
};
$htmlBack = $('.bouncer').clone();
moveInterval = setInterval(moveIt, 50);
$('button').on('click', function(){
  if( moveInterval != 0){
    clearInterval(moveInterval);
    $('.bouncer').remove();
    $('.bouncyHouse').eq(0).append($htmlBack);
    $htmlBack = $('.bouncer').clone();
    moveInterval = 0;
  } else {
    moveInterval = setInterval(moveIt, 50);
  }
});
```

```css
.bouncyHouse {
  height: 200px;
  width: 150%;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.bouncer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
}

.bouncer:nth-child(2) {
  top: 30px;
  left: 100px;
}

.bouncer:nth-child(3) {
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bouncyHouse">
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>

  <div class="bouncer" data-vx='2' data-vy='-3'>
    <span>space</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bouncer" data-vx='-2' data-vy='2'>
    <span>space</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bouncer" data-vx='5' data-vy='2'>
    <span>space</span>
  </div>
</div>
```